# Length of stay in Burkina Faso

Tags: visas, burkina-faso

On Burkina Faso’s government website, “[Entry conditions](https://www.visaburkina.bf/en/entry-visas-to-burkina-faso-the-long-term-visa/)” says

> the total duration of stays cannot exceed ninety days per semester

which sounds like Schengen’s 90/180 rule.  But “[Stay conditions](https://www.visaburkina.bf/en/stay-conditions-while-in-burkina-faso/)” says

> Any foreigner who wishes to stay in Burkina Faso for a period
> exceeding ninety (90) days must hold either a long-stay visa, a
> residence permit …

which sounds like either instrument would allow, e.g., a visit of 150 days.

I couldn’t find any information on the residence permit.  I’m not interested in moving there.  I’m just trying to find out what it takes to not have to get out in only ninety days.

A non-government site claims one can request an extension of a short-stay visa, but that might not be granted, and it still requires counting days to apply for it in time.

Comment: Mmmm, some quality information there: *"…must hold either a long-stay visa, a residence permit, or a residence permit." [sic]*